# Little o notation in Taylor's formula : o(1)

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, definition

I see multiple versions of Taylor's formula (some call it Taylor's series ( I dont really know whats the difference ) but one I know pretty well is :

$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+f''(a)\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}+f^{3}(a)\frac{(x-a)^3}{3!}+...+f^{n}(a)\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}+(x-a)^n o(1)$

I get the idea of approximating a function using its derivatives , but I cant really understand what is the $(x-a)^n$ o(1) part doing . I know it means the left is negligble to 1 somewhere , but is it a function or other notation  ? Why choosing $(x-a)^n$ on the left ? And what does it really mean here? Thank you

Edit: Converted formulas to Latex formatting - Felix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, $o(1)$ is an unknown function of $x$ that converges to $0$ when $x\to a$. This takes a while to get used to, but it is an incredibly useful notation.

The complete term $(x-a)^no(1)$ is a $(x-a)^n$ times a function that converges to $0$. In other words it is a function that converges to $0$ after being divided by $(x-a)^n$. This can be rewritten as $o((x-a)^n)$, which can be interpreted as "goes to $0$ faster than $(x-a)^n$.

Remark that you never know what function the $o(1)$ exactly is. Only that it converges to $0$. So for instance an equation $o(1) + o(1) = o(1)$ is valid.It means that the sum of two function that goes to $0$ still goes to $0$. Something important to know is that $o(1)-o(1) \neq 0$, because the two small o's are not necessarily the same functions. The only thing you can say is $o(1)-o(1) = o(1)$. Another weird thing is that you can replace a $o((x-a)^5)$ by a $o(1)$, but not the other way around (the first one is a stronger condition).

Let me give you a list of examples of manipulations of small o's, when $x\to a$ like in your example.
$$ o(1) + o(x-a) = o(1)+o(1) = o(1).$$
$$ o(1)/(1+o(1)) = o(1)/1 = o(1).$$
$$ (x-a)^3o(x-a) = (x-a)^3(x-a)o(1) = o((x-a)^4).$$
If $a\neq 0$,
$$ xo(1) = ao(1) = o(1).$$
If $a=0,$
$$ xo(1) = o(x).$$

Comment: "Another weird thing is that you can replace a $o((x−a)^5)$ by a $o(1)$, but not the other way around (the first one is a stronger condition)."
That is why I like to use the element notation instead of the equal sign, because they are really classes of functions. So the element sign gives you a little bit better idea what this is all about.

Answer (score 4):

If $f\in o(g(x)),\, x\rightarrow 0$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=0$ now $h(x)o(g(x))=o(h(x)g(x))$ because:
$$
f \in o(g(x)) \Rightarrow 0=\lim\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=\lim\left|\frac{h(x)f(x)}{h(x)g(x)}\right|
$$
Thus for every $f\in o(g),\ h(x)f(x)\in o(h(x)g(x))$

So in your case $(x-a)^no(1)=o((x-a)^n), \, x\rightarrow a$ which is simply the peano residual.
In words: when a tends to x the point your taylor approximation is approximating the error will tend to 0 with a speed faster than a polynomial with degree n.

Comment: It's good to use `\lim` as opposed to `lim` and to use `\,` to space out single entities, like functions or differentials, that consist of more than one symbol.

Comment: Why is there a downvote for a correct answer? The only problem is minor latex typos. +1 to counter the downvote.

Comment: A minor correction needed in last sentence. The error tends to $0$ faster than polynomial $(x-a) ^{n} $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  This answer is very ambiguous, I can't understand that notation (random usage of $\rightarrow $ and  $ \implies$ ...etc. I think he must explain what did he mean.

Comment: @Freshman42: I don't see any ambiguity in those symbols. The single arrow $\to$ is for "tends to" and the double arrow $\Rightarrow $ is for logical implication. Both the uses are standard and do not need explanation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh : $o(g(x)) is an intervall? execuse me if this seems obvious to you.

Comment: @Freshman42: $o(g(x)) $ is not an interval. Rather it is set of all functions $f$ such that $f(x) /g(x) \to 0$. That's the meaning of notation little-o. And the meaning and notation and pretty standard.

Comment: @Freshman42 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation I try to remember to look at wikipedia to make sure I am not using professor specific stuff.

Comment: You do need to make sure that $h(x)$ is nonzero near $x=0$, however.